# How to secure RepositoryRestResource in spring data rest

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data-rest

I have a spring data repository and I used `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation to generate REST resources for it. Now I want to control access on it using spring security.

I know it is possible to put `@PreAutorize` on methods or use `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to perform authorization according to request paths. But none of these solutions work for me. Because the former secures the methods while I need to only apply it when a HTTP request is trying to call method and the latter seems bad to me because I need to modify a single class after adding each new repository. (kinda violation of Open-Closed Principle, IMHO) if I I prefer to put access control rules of each resource beside that resource not to put somewhere else and tie them using paths or names.

So I have two criteria for the access control solution:

1. I want to apply it only on HTTP requests.
2. I want to define it in its own class not somewhere else.

```
@RepositoryRestResource
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
public interface VehicleRepository extends CrudRepository<Vehicle,Integer>{

}
```

This is the first solution which does not work for me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        prePostEnabled = true,
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

...

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       ...

       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/vehicles/**").hasRole("ADMIN");

       ...
    }

...

}
```

and this a second solution which I don't like as I described.

I'd like to know if there is any other solutions. I've read reference documentations and searched the web but I didn't find what I want.
Note that I want to use `RepositoryRestResource` so please don't say "write your own controller".

Sorry for long question and thank you in advance.

Comment: Put all secured end-points on a specific path say `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/secured/**").hasRole("ADMIN");`

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the methods from CrudRepository, like this:

```java
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@Override
Optional<Vehicle> findById(Integer id);
```

You can find more information in the Spring Data REST Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#security